# Unit Test Loop gets executed more than once

Tags: java, unit-testing

For some reason the loop inside a method, that gets executed in a unit test, gets executed more than once. And because of that I get `ConcurrentModificationException`. To make it short, method loops through objects, executes other method on each object, with `Runnable` parameter. This works just fine when application is deployed, but during unit testing, loop gets executed more than once and I get an error.

Code example:

```
@RunWith(JukitoRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Inject
    MainService mainService;

    @Test
    public void testMain(){
        mainService.setData(mainService.getSelectedData());
    }
}

public class MainService {

    List<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();

    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();

    public MainService(){
        /* this.fields is filled here*/
        data.add(/*data obj*/);
        data.add(/*data obj*/);
        data.add(/*data obj*/);
    }

    public List<Data> getSelectedData(){
        /* alghoritm to filter data */
        return data; /*returns List with 1 and 2nd data objects from this.data*/
    }
    private void deleteEl(Field field, Runnable callback){
        fields.remove(field);
        for (ListIterator<Data> i = data.listIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Data data = i.next();
            if(data.something()) i.remove();
        }

        if (callback != null) {
            callback.run();
        }
    }

    public void setData(List<Data> selected){
        for(Field field : fields){// checked with debug, this gets executed more than once, why?! It should run only once. ConcurrentModificationException gets thrown here.
            if(field instanceof Object){
                deleteEl(field, new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        create(selected); //won't post create() code, since even commenting this, does not help. Error persists
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Have You tried debugging it step by step and/or setting breakpoints to inspect what could be the cause? What error is thrown? And why is there a test case with no assertions?

Comment: You delete while iterating through `fields`. This is a bug not related to the test.

Comment: `setData` iterates through `fields`, and calls `deleteEl`. `deleteEl` calls `fields.remove(field)`. You can't do that.

Comment: I just posted bare bones of the test, only the part that is the cause, hence no assertions....

Comment: @nbrooks, that makes sence, but why Can't I reproduce this bug when application is deployed? Damn, even at production server I can't reproduce this. Only after i wrote unit test (code was not written by me and ofcourse there was no unit test..) did I run into this.

Comment: I can't say why your production code is or isn't working, but the `ConcurrentModificationException` error you're seeing here is because of the code mentioned above. That's definitely a bug. If you have a different issue, with different code, feel free to post that. As an FYI, `remove(obj)` does loop through the collection as well, which you might be confusing with your outer loop.

Comment: Maybe you only have a single item in production? :)

Answer (score 2):

The exception occurs because you remove a field from the `fields` list (first line in `deleteEl` method) while iterating over the fields list (`for(Field field : fields)`.

Btw. I assume the check for `(field instanceof Object)` always returns true.

Comment: If `field` is null then `field instanceof Object` would return false. So it's a complicated null check here I guess...

Comment: aggreed, explicit check for `field != null` would be more comprehensible

Comment: `Btw. I assume the check for (field instanceof Object) always returns true.` Wrong assumption. Anyway, problem has something to do with @nbrooks notes, though it's a bit more complicated

Comment: I don't get it, either its a `Field`, a subtype of `Field` or `null` ... so why don't check for null instead?

Comment: Field is just an example, it doesn't relate to problem at hand, so I didn't bother to post my real code. In truth, instead of field would be a Base class, and there are several different extensions of that class, so there's a check wether Base is of a particular instance (not lang.Object obviously).